# Array of generic structs that confrom to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a protocol called Endpoint

```swift
public protocol Endpoint {
    associatedtype ModelType: Codable

    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var headers: [String: String] { get }
    var parameters: Parameters? { get set }
    var customTimeout: TimeInterval? { get }
}
```

I then have a few endpoints conforming to that protocol.

```swift
struct CurrenciesEndpoint: Endpoint { /* ... */ }

struct UserEndpoint: Endpoint { /* ... */ }

struct BalanceEndpoint: Endpoint { /* ... */ }
```

I want to fetch these endpoints in a `DispatchGroup` and once I get all the data from them I will create another object encapsulating all their responses. Like this

```swift
class DashboardResponseModel {
    public var currency: CurrencyResponse?
    public var user: UserResponse?
    public var balance: BalanceResponse?
}
```

I wanted to create a structure like this

```swift
struct EndpointMapping<T: Endpoint> {
    let endpoint: T
    let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<DashboardResponseModel, T.ModelType?>
}
```

Then in my `fetch()` method I wanted to create an array of `EndpointMapping` for each endpoint.

```swift
var endpointMappings: [EndpointMapping] = []
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: CurrenciesEndpoint(), keyPath: \. currency),
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: UserEndpoint(), keyPath: \. user),
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: BalanceEndpoint(), keyPath: \. balance),
]
```

I am forced to give a type to array description but I need that array to be any type of `Endpoint`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You are probably better off not to use Protocols at all in this scenario. Looking at your protocol, you also seem to want to get the Model value somewhere. But that is also an abstract type. What you eventually get at max would be an `AnyModel` value. This is a pretty opaque type, raising the question what one could do with this anyway. So, I would suggest to not go this route and change the design.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper what kind of design for example?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. From a very high point of view, you probably want to fetch one or more domain objects from a service which is represented as encoded values which can be decoded into some Swift struct. Well, the actual type of your desired Swift struct strongly depends on your Use Case. Also, the number of endpoints you need to fetch and how you compose your final swift struct from each endpoint data is very use case specific as well. You probably should not try to find a generic solution at all. It's too specific for a use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need get rid from associatedtype in protocol and from keypath in EndpointMapping.

```
public protocol Endpoint {
    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var headers: [String: String] { get }
    var parameters: Parameters? { get set }
    var customTimeout: TimeInterval? { get }
}

struct EndpointMapping {
    let endpoint: Endpoint
    let dataAcceptor: (Data) throws -> Void
}

extension DashboardResponseModel {
    func getDataAcceptor<T>(by keyPath: WritableKeyPath<DashboardResponseModel, T>) -> (Data) throws -> Void {
    {
        self[keyPath: keyPath] = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to store different kinds of EndpointMapping in one array. To do this you need to declare an intermediate protocol and use it in the array declaration with keyword `any`. Like this:

```
protocol EndpointMappingProtocol {
    associatedtype Endpoint
    var endpoint: Endpoint { get }
}

struct EndpointMapping<T: Endpoint>: EndpointMappingProtocol {
    let endpoint: T
}

var endpointMappings: [any EndpointMappingProtocol] = [
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: CurrenciesEndpoint()),
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: UserEndpoint()),
    EndpointMapping(endpoint: BalanceEndpoint()),
]
```

I removed the `keyPath` argument for clarity.